# Unable to build JIT enabled Octave for Windows

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, octave, jit

My goal is creating the lowest size octave with jit enabled and without GUI for windows. BTW I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

I tried some combinations but I couldn't figure it out. 
First, my configuration was something like this:

> --enable-devel-tools --enable-octave=stable --enable-binary-packages --enable-jit --disable-java --disable-docs

and I get "unsupported LLVM configuration" error.

When I look llvm make file I saw an if code:

```
ifeq ($(MXE_NATIVE_BUILD),yes) ...
```

So, I came back to configure and from this point I use this conf. setting:

> --enable-native-build --enable-jit

I get some other errors but I finally stuck with this error:

```
o@ubuntu:~/mxe-octave$ make nsis-installer JOBS=10
/bin/bash: line 0: pwd: -W: invalid option 
pwd: usage: pwd [-LP] 
/bin/bash: line 0: pwd: -W: invalid option 
pwd: usage: pwd [-LP] 
[check requirements] 
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/o/mxe-octave/installed-packages/build-python', 
needed by '/home/o/mxe-octave/installed-packages/build-mako'. Stop."
```

So:

1- jit-enabled windows octave build is really possible?

2- Is this a proper bug, if it is, how can I get over it.

Thanks

Comment: These three things don't match: "for windows", "using Ubuntu", "native-build". If you are compiling for Windows on Ubuntu, you're not doing a native build, you are cross-compiling.

Comment: So, I try to avoid building LLVM package, If it's possible. thank you.

Comment: You're wasting your time if your only problem is building with JIT enabled. At the moment, Octave's JIT compiler is not worth the trouble, it's just a proof of concept and is useless in real case scenarios.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38724963/1609556