# Sparse matrix to speed up octave

Tags: performance, vectorization, octave, sparse-matrix

I have a loop where "i" depends on "i-1" value, so I cannot vectorize it.
I've read that I can use a sparse matrix in order to vectorize it and so to speed up my code, but I don't understand how this work.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Sparse matrices are useful to represent matrices with lots of zero elements in them. It makes no sense that they would allow to vectorize code that can’t be vectorized without them. Anyway, loops haven’t been slow in MATLAB in 15 years. If your loop is a bottleneck in your program, show us the code (but see [mre]), we might have ideas for how to speed it up.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it does make sense actually; see my answer below -- I'm pretty sure this is what OP was referring to. Obviously the applicability of this method is rather limited, but it's still quite a neat little trick.

Comment: Sorry about my MATLAB comment, didn’t pay attention and realize this was tagged Octave. The rest of my comment still stands, and the last part is most important: please post some code so we can try speed it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to [this technique](http://www.variousconsequences.com/2008/12/more-on-speeding-up-octave.html), as referenced from this (rather old) [how to speed up octave](http://www.variousconsequences.com/2009/01/how-to-speed-up-octave.html) article.

I'll rephrase the gist here in case the link dies in the future.

Suppose you have the following loop:

```
p1(1) = 0;

for i = 2 : N
    t     = t + dt;
    p1(i) = p1(i - 1) + dt * 2 * t;
endfor
```

You note here that, purely from a *mathematical* point of view, the last step in the loop could be rephrased as:

```
-1 * p1(i - 1) + 1 * p1(i) = dt * 2 * t
```

This makes it possible to recast the problem as a sparse matrix solve, by thinking of p1 as the vector of unknowns, and each iteration of the loop as a row in a (sparse) system of equations. E.g.:

[image]

Given that `t` is a known vector, this makes the above a straightforward problem that can be solved via a simple matrix division operation, which is guaranteed to be fast.

---

Having said that, presumably this 'trick' is only useful if you are able to recast the problem in this manner in the first place. Presumably this will only be the case for linear problems of your unknown. I don't think this can necessarily be used for more complicated loops.

Also, as Cris has mentioned in the comments, if this method does not work for you, there's a chance you can optimize your loop in other ways (or even that the loop solution may not necessarily be slow in the first place).

By the way, in theory, Octave provides jit-speedup like matlab does, though unlike matlab you need to enable it explicitly (in the sense that you need to compile your octave with jit options, which tends not to be the default), and my personal experience is that this is mostly experimental and may not do much except in the simplest of loops (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38721749/4183191)).

Comment: Sure, if you can write the problem as a system of linear equations with lots of zeros, then a sparse matrix is helpful. Fair enough. Nice writeup!

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. Thanks